# JSONException showing in android volley,php,mysql xampp

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am working on an android project.I am having the problem with login activity.
I am getting JSONException for not converting String into JSONObject and also connection timeout error.
I am using android volley Library, MySQL XAMPP server.

Here are my
Login.php

```
    <?php

include("Connection.php");

if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
{

   $email=$_POST["email"];

   $password=$_POST["password"];

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from user_master where email='$email' && password='$password'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {   
        echo "success";
        exit;
    }           
    else
    {   
        echo "INVALID";
        exit;
    }
}


?>
```

LoginRequest.java

```
package com.talentakeaways.ttpms;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;



import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by chand on 15-03-2018.
 */

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {


    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.26.16.22:80/Ttpms/login.php";
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, listener, errorListener);
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("email", username);
        parameters.put("password", password);
    }
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

Ttpm_Login.java

```
    package com.talentakeaways.ttpms;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.R;

public class Ttpm_Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    //declaration of edit text, button and string values
    EditText tenantname, passWord;
    Button bt_login;
    String userName, password;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ttpm_login);
        setTitle("Login"); //set title of the activity
        initialize();
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Ttpm_Login.this);
        //onClickListener method for button
        bt_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //assigning String variables to the text in edit texts
                userName = tenantname.getText().toString();
                password = passWord.getText().toString();
                //Validating the String values
                if (validateUsername(userName) && validatePassword(password)) {

                    //Start ProgressDialog
                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Ttpm_Login.this);
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging You In");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.show();


                    //LoginRequest from class LoginRequest
                    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(userName, password, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.i("Login Response", response);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                //If Success then start Dashboard Activity
                                if (jsonObject.getBoolean("success")) {

                                    Intent loginSuccess = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Ttpm_Dashboard.class);
                                    startActivity(loginSuccess);
                                    finish();
                                }

                                //else Invalid
                                else {
                                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("INVALID"))
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords Don't Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.getStackTraceString(e);
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Bad Response from the Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Connection Timed Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Bad Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(loginRequest);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialize() {
        tenantname = findViewById(R.id.tenantname);
        passWord = findViewById(R.id.password);
        bt_login = findViewById(R.id.login);
    }

    private boolean validateUsername(String string) {
        //Validating the entered USERNAME
        if (string.equals("")) {
            tenantname.setError("Enter a Username");
            return false;
        } else if (string.length() > 50) {
            tenantname.setError("Maximum 50 Characters");
            return false;
        } else if (string.length() < 6) {
            tenantname.setError("Minimum 6 Characters");
            return false;
        }
        tenantname.setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validatePassword(String string) {
        //Validating the entered PASSWORD
        if (string.equals("")) {
            passWord.setError("Enter Your Password");
            return false;
        } else if (string.length() > 32) {
            passWord.setError("Maximum 32 Characters");
            return false;
        }
//        else if (string.length() < 8) {
//            passWord.setError("Minimum 8 Characters");
//            return false;
//        }
//
        passWord.setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }

}
```

please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

you are trying to read the response as a Json, but the response is not a Json at all. Please, open your php page with postman, so you can see the responde you get and properly understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

When your PHP server returns information, it's the characters

```
success
```

or

```
INVALID
```

But if you try to parse these values as JSON, you will get a failure

```
JSON.parse("success")
09:59:02.442 VM271:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse
```

Valid JSON values are [string, number, array, object, true, false, and null](https://json.org/)

So you could fix your PHP server to echo a string, number, array, object, true, false or null, like so

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{   
    echo '"success"';
    exit;
}           
else
{   
    echo '"INVALID"';
    exit;
}
```